# Quality factor limit for 2nd order RC passive band-pass filter

Tags: circuit-design, passive-filter, band-pass

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3leZF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm designing a 2nd Order passive RC band-pass filter and found that the quality factor is given by:

\$Q=\frac{\sqrt{C_1C_2R_1R_2}}{C_1R_1+C_2R_1+C_2R_2}\$

When i make Q = (value > ~0.5) and solve for \$C_1\$, for example, Wolfram Mathematica always give me complex or negative answers. So, my question is: are there any limits for Q factor in passive circuits or I just done something wrong?

Comment: Nearly correct. Would you consider passive LC bandpass? The limits of Q are mostly constrained by the source resistance and load resistance when compared to L & C reactance. Now Q can be much larger. In your RC example, source R and load R constrain Q to even lower limits (you haven't yet considered these constraints).

Comment: The Q factor of a passive RC circuit can never exceed Qmax=0.5. This is because the poles are always negative-real (and cannot be complex)

Comment: @Lvw But how can i proof that? I came upon this value by simply putting numbers in the formula.

Comment: @glen_geek Yes, I`m redesigning it to be RLC, but I need to justify in the project report why i didn't choose RC.

Comment: Vinicius, find the transfer function and identify the zeros of the denominator (poles of the transfer function). You will see that the well known formula for finding the roots of a quadratic function will always led to REAL solutions. Now - applying the definition of Q expressed through pole parameters you will see that always q<0.5.   Examples: For R1=R2 and C1=C2 we have Q=1/3 and for R1C1=R2C2 but with R2>>R1 and C2<<C1 we have Q very close to 0.5.

Comment: I have already found the transfer function and roots, but i didn't understand this part "definition of Q expressed through pole parameters". (Sorry, I'm in a first course of electric circuits)

Comment: Vinicius, sorry for the late answer. The quality of a pole is defined as Qp=wp/(2*sigma) with wp=pole frequency (magnitude of the pointer from the origin to the pole location) and sigma=Real part of the complex pole (on the negative real axis of the s-plane).

Comment: @LvW I`m sorry for the super-late reply. (I forgot to do it). Based on what you have said (find transfer function...identify the zeros...quadratic function), I figured out how to proof the limitation of Q mathematically. I answered my own question today. Would you mind looking at the answer, just to make sure there's nothing wrong?

Comment: Vinicius - why do you think we have "active filters" based on amplifiers with feedback? Answer: Because passive RC-filters do not allow quality factors >0.5. In your circuit, we have Q<0.5. Only in case of decoupling both parts with a buffer a value of Q=0.5 is possible. If you want pasive filters with Q>0.5 you are required to use LC-resonance. However, inductors have a lot of disadvantages and limitations - that`s the case for active filters which "emulate" the inductor effect (creating conjugate-complex poles with Q>0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to prove mathematically that the Q factor of this band-pass RC circuit is limited to: $$ 0<Q<0.5 $$

---

First, we need to remember that the standard form of the transfer function for a second-order band-pass filter is: 
$$H(s)=\frac{K(2ζω_n)s}{(s^2+2ζω_ns+ω_n^2 )}$$
Where:

- \$K\$ is the maximum gain of the filter
- \$ζ\$ is the damping ratio
- \$ω_n\$ is the undamped natural frequency

And the transfer function based on component values is:
$$H(s)=\frac{sC_1 R_1}{C_1 C_2 R_1 R_2 \cdot s^2+(C_1 R_1+C_2 R_1+C_2 R_2)s+1}$$

---

To prove that 0 < Q < 0.5, I will start by setting up an equation that, when solved, give the poles (roots of the denominator) of the above transfer function:
$$C_1 C_2 R_1 R_2 s^2+(C_1 R_1+C_2 R_1+C_2 R_2)s+1=0$$

Note that this expression is a quadratic equation in the form \$ as^2+bs+c=0\$. Its discriminant is given by \$Δ=b^2-4ac\$. So, we have:

$$Δ=(C_1 R_1+C_2 R_1+C_2 R_2)^2-4⋅C_1 C_2 R_1 R_2$$
Assuming that \$ C_1>0\$, \$ C_2>0\$, \$R_1>0\$ and \$R_2>0\$, it follows that \$Δ>0\$ for any choice of components.

Now, doing the same process but using the standard form this time, we have:
$$s^2+2ζω_n s+ω_n^2=0$$
$$Δ=(2ζω_n )^2-4ω_n^2=4ζ^2 ω_n^2-4ω_n^2=4ω_n^2⋅(ζ^2-1)$$
But we already know that \$Δ>0\$. So, using the standard form:

$$4ω_n^2⋅(ζ^2-1)>0$$

The term \$4ω_n^2\$ is surely positive. Then, to satisfy the above inequality, its necessary that 
$$(ζ^2-1)>0$$
Before proceeding, it's important to remember one more thing: 
$$Q≜\frac{1}{2ζ} \implies ζ=\frac{1}{2Q}$$
Then, by making the substitution, we have:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2Q}\right)^2-1>0 \implies \left|\frac{1}{2Q}\right|>1$$ 
Analyzing the expression of Q factor for the filter, we have, doing the same assumptions made above with \$Δ\$:
$$Q=\frac{\sqrt{C_1C_2R_1R_2}}{C_1R_1+C_2R_1+C_2R_2}>0$$
Thus, we can finally conclude that:
$$\frac{1}{2Q}>1 \implies 0<Q<0.5$$

Comment: 100% correct. Gratulations!